# Can't open edmx.sql file in VS

Tags: visual-studio, edmx

I have edmx-model that have been created on another computer.
On another computer creation SQL-DB was successful.

After import edmx on current machine - I have been deleted next files:
model.designer.cs
model.edmx.sql

Then I select - generate DB from model.

model.designer.cs and model.edmx.sql then regenerated.

But when I try to open model.edmx.sql file in VS to execute it - nothing happens.
Just blank work area in VS and nothing more.

What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try right clicking on the SQL file, select 'Open With', then select 'Notepad', and see if the file opens in Notepad.

**[EDIT]** The thread [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/27ef7c94-4410-4925-ab22-3fec475b1885) seems to have a solution.

To paraphrase:

```
To fix the issue of not being able to load the RadLangSvc.Package here is what you need to do:

1. Load up your ISO or DVD VS2010 Installer in an explorer window

2. Go to the WCU foldler

3. Go to the DAC folder

4. Install MSI's

    i. DACFramework_enu.msi
   ii. DACProjectSystemSetup_enu.msi
  iii. TSqlLanguageService_enu.msi
```

Comment: When blank screen appears - VS begin to consume 25% of proccessor, and memory consuming permanently grows.

Comment: And it also happens on new model with two simple entities.

Comment: How was I to know it opens in Notepad? The only articles I can find suggest running a repair on Visual Studio, or removing SQL Express if you have that installed alongside a 'Full' SQL install. I appreciate both of those options are a headache though. Perhaps if you can open it in Notepad you can copy it into SQL Server Management Studio and at least get it executed to ensure your DB is up to date?

Comment: I have edited my response with a link to a thread I believe will help.

Comment: Thanks man, I got a problemk with my MS VS instalation. Too sad.